# error: package com.flutter.stripe does not exist

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, stripe-payments

I'm trying to run an implementation of [flutter_stripe](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe) in my Flutter project, following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-43zM01ThQ). When I run the project, this error occurs:

```
C:\Users\Braiscompany\Documents\Braiscompany-Bag\bag\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:31: error: package com.flutter.stripe does not exist
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.flutter.stripe.StripeAndroidPlugin());
                                                         ^
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 50s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Somebody already had and solve this error? Because I don't know what is occurring. Thanks for the attention.

Edit: As they asked me in the comments, this is the pubspec.yaml file of my project. The Android Studio don't report any error.

```
name: ***
description: ***

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.12

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  getwidget: ^2.0.4 #colocar o avatar retangular
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  firebase_core: ^1.6.0 # recursos basicos do firebase
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.1 # banco de dados
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.0 # armazenamento de arquivos
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.0 # autenticacao do usuario
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0 # fontes do google
  image_picker: ^0.6.0+10 #selecionar imagens
  brasil_fields: ^1.1.4 # aplicar padrões brasileiros
  intl: ^0.17.0 # aplicar padrões monetarios
  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0 # carousel do detalhesBagagem
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.7
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.7
  random_string: ^2.3.1
  rounded_loading_button: ^2.0.5
  load: ^1.0.0
  ionicons: ^0.1.2 # icones do ionicons
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0 # spinners para os loadings
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.5.1 # picker de data e hora
  animations: ^2.0.1 # animações em flutter
  #flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0 # import para login do facebook
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0 # barra de avaliacao
  rating_dialog: ^2.0.1 # avaliacao para o feedback do usuario
  search_widget: ^1.0.2 # busca para mensagens de usuario
  #onesignal_flutter: ^3.2.3 # notificações
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.6 # notificações do firebase
  toggle_switch: ^1.2.0 # botao binario de switch
  customtoggleswitch: ^1.1.0 # botao de toggle switch
  http: ^0.13.3 # API para requisicoes em http
  flutter_animated_dialog: ^2.0.1 #Permite Dialogs Animados
  image_cropper: ^1.4.1 # ajuste de tamanho da imagem
  date_format: ^2.0.4 # formatacao de data
  autocomplete_textfield: ^1.7.3 # autocomplete para inputs
  basic_utils: ^3.5.0 # utilidades basicas
  password_strength: ^0.2.0 # forca da senha
  intro_slider: ^3.0.2 # slides de introducao
  #about: ^1.4.0 # pagina de "sobre"
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0 # permite adicionar um arquivo svg ao projeto
  url_launcher: ^6.0.10 # acesso de URLs no app
  qr_flutter: ^4.0.0 # plugin de QR Code
  share_extend: ^2.0.0 # compartilhamento de arquivos
  path_provider: ^2.0.3 # para converter arquivos
  email_validator: ^2.0.1 # validar email
  syncfusion_flutter_sliders: ^19.2.59 # para fazer o slider de saque
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2 # para o icone do ap
  #cielo_ecommerce: any # para a API de pagamentos
  credit_card_field: ^1.0.2 # para a animacao do cartao de credito
  flutter_credit_card: ^2.0.0 # para animacao do cartao de credito
  #stripe_payment: ^1.1.1 # pagamentos via stripe
  flutter_stripe: ^1.3.0 # pagamentoa via stripe
  stripe_sdk: any

dev_dependencies:

  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  assets:
    - images/logo1.png
    - images/logo2.png
    - images/facebook.png
    - images/usuario.png
    - images/b-background-conversas.jpg
    - images/briefcase1.png
    - images/briefcase2.png
    - images/Group1.png
    - images/Logo.png
    - images/google.png
    - images/google2.png
    - images/facebook2.png
    - images/intro1.png
    - images/vendaBagagemInicial.png
    - images/vendaBagagemInicial2.png
    - images/vendaBagagemInicial3.png
    - images/vendaBagagemInicial4.png
    - images/vendaBagagemInicial5.png
    - images/vendaBagagemInicial6.png
    - images/vendaBagagemInicial7.png
    - images/iconeCompletoVertical.png
    - images/logoTotal-old.svg
    - images/logoSVG.svg
    - images/qrcode.png
    - images/beta.png
    - images/google-logo.png
    - images/facebook-logo.png
    - texts/devs.md
    - texts/termos-de-uso.md



  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: Share your pubspec.yaml file here.

Comment: Your sdk should be modified to this, right?  ">=2.5.0 <3.0.0" . 

There is no flutter sdk above 2.5.2 right now.